# Amazon SNS vs PubNub vs Parse for a webrtc

Tags: push-notification, webrtc, amazon-sns, pubnub, callkit

I am implementing a webrtc app using twilio platform (for both ios and android). To be consistent with  iOS 10, I need to integrate the CallKit which is activted in response to an external notificationn, such as a VoIP push notification. I was wondering which platform is better (e.g Amazon SNS, PubNub, Parse etc) would be better for implementing the push notification in back-end (I use node.js).

Note: I have seen some discussion/question regarding pubub vs SNS (e.g What is advantage and disadvantage of using pubnub over Amazon Simple Notification Service (sns)?). But those discussion are pretty old (3 years ago). In addition, they do not address/cover Callkit!

Comment: [What is advantage and disadvantage of using pubnub over Amazon Simple Notification Service (sns)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20843632/what-is-advantage-and-disadvantage-of-using-pubnub-over-amazon-simple-notificati)

Answer (score 2):

tl;dr - use OneSignal, stay away from SNS

I haven't tried pubNub, but implementing VoIP Push notifications with SNS in Node was pretty straightforward.
You need to pay close attention that you're signing the SNS platform application with the correct certificate. 
Using the aws npm module was a breeze.

Two things I didn't like about SNS:

1. If SNS fails to send to an endpoint, it'll disable that endpoint,
   which can make testing pretty frustrating. The same behavior happens
   with normal push notifications as well.  That can happen quite often
   with QA devices, which undergo frequent factory resets, or where the
   tested app is being repeatedly uninstalled/reinstalled.
2. Compared to other push notifications services, getting proper metrics from SNS  is a real pain. Yes, you should be able to connect
   SNS them to CloudWatch, but the result is very basic and years
   behind the standards that other providers (like Parse or OneSignal)
   have been offering for free.

**UPDATE June 2018**

OneSignal now supports VoIP Push notifications. I would definitely recommend using their services as they are free and are vastly superior to SNS.